# Unrecognised font family in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have problem with custom fonts in the react-native.

I followed instructions but it still gives me this error `Unrecognised font family SFUIDisplay-Bold'`

I checked the Xcode and in the font lists I have this.

[image]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57506525/react-native-paper-unrecognized-font-family-material-icons

Comment: Sometimes the file name and font name can be different. If you are using mac then install the font and see the PostScript name. If it is different then use that name in React native styles.